# Как обрезать строку по количеству символов и до ближайшего пробела?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция:

```js
const trimText = (text, length, end = '') => {
  return text.length <= length ?
    text :
    `${text.substr(0, length)}${end}`;
};

const text = 'Надо как то правильно обрезать от пробела'
const res = trimText(text, 15, end = '...')
console.log(res)
```

надо что бы было так: `Надо как то правильно...` а не `Надо как то прав...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.indexOf(искомая_подстрока, начальная_позиция)` — найти первый пробел после указанного length и резать до него.

```js
let text = 'Надо как то правильно обрезать от пробела';

console.log( trimText(text, 15, end='...') );

function trimText(text, length, end = '') {
  let index = text.indexOf(" ", length);
  if( index == -1 ) index = length;
  
  return text.slice(0, index) + end;
}
```

Если бы не он, можно было через `.split(" ")` начать добавлять элементы в финальную строку, `while( result.length < length )`

Или,

```js
let text = 'Надо как то правильно обрезать от пробела';

console.log( trimText(text, 4, end='...') );
console.log( trimText(text, 5, end='...') );

function trimText(text, length, end = '') {
  let result = text.slice(0, length);
  let i = length;
  
  while( text[i] && text[i] != " " ) {
    result += text[ i++ ];
  }
  
  return result + end;
}
```

Comment: Эх... Надо мне прокачать скил разгадки ребусов в заголовках вопросов... :)

Comment: @UModeL И не понятно, как его отредактировать, чтобы кто-то со схожей проблемой нашел ответ)